# Count down timer Android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Hi i want to make an count down timer and i made one and it work but,
the cout down timer take the System.currentTimeMillis(); .
When i change the time on a device the time on a counter is changed to.
How to make a timer that is not depend on a System.currentTime.
Maybe firebase FieldValue.serverTimestamp()? but how?
And sorry if i post something wrong posting first time.

```
package com.example.backgroundtimer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS =  3600000 ;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
    private long mEndTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });
        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateButtons();
            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning = true;
        updateButtons();
    }

    private void pauseTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        updateButtons();
    }

    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int hours = (int)  (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        int minutes = (int) (int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis/ (1000*60)) % 60);
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }

    private void updateButtons() {
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < START_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
        editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
        editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
        editor.apply();
        if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
        Toast.makeText(this,"t "+mTimeLeftInMillis,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
        updateCountDownText();
        updateButtons();
        if (mTimerRunning) {
            mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
            mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
                mTimerRunning = false;
                updateCountDownText();
                updateButtons();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you change the time on your device? What period of time do you use for your timer?

Comment: the timer i want to use for a card game with a wheel of fortune the wheel is turnable only when timer is finished so every 2 hours.But users can cheat the timer by changing the time zone or a time in a device.I want to make an timer independent from a device time.